# Why is this CSS:before statement not working in IE 8, IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element, css-content

Using a :before CSS to get an image/icon here (see round circle in image below), but in Internet explorer 8+ it is just not showing up.

This is the site:
http://www.websiteprofessioneel.nl

Image link below shows right element (it's the icon in the first post header) as circled on this screendump
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xxd9f&s=5#.Ul_WajZRoWY

this is the CSS for that:

```css
.welpen h2:before {
    content: url("/wp-content/uploads/z-welpen-category-small.png") !important;
}
```

Anything missing perhaps? All other browsers work fine and as far as I know peudo CSS is totally supported in at least IE9, but it's not working in both IE8, 9 and up.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE10 either.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is probably due to the wrong doctype. I don't know which one would be the right one, but read up on proper doctypes for IE and see if it helps to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## IE is Probably Using [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)

Internet Explorer can run in quirks or standards mode. The purpose of quirks mode was to make the new standards-compliant IEs (8+) able to read and process the code people had previously written for IE7-.

**Likely Reason #1: invalid or absent DOCTYPE declaration**

Try specifying this on the first line of your HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Make sure the `<html>` element is present. Even though HTML5 specification says it's not needed, older IEs (10 and older) tend to enter quirks mode when it's not specified.

**Likely reason #2: site fails (X)HTML validation**

If this is present, make sure the W3C validator throws no errors as these can also trigger Quirks Mode in IE. [Yours has 15](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://gig.isdesignstaging.nl/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

**Actual reason was more unlikely: deliberately triggering Quirks Mode**

After comments discussion, turns out I was right about the quirks mode, but wrong about the reason. Make sure you don't have any meta tags telling IE to run in quirks mode such as this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Comment: There's already a valid doctype that would prevent IE from going into quirks mode, and the appropriate `<html>` tags.

Comment: In that case, probably one of the issues [identified by the validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgig.isdesignstaging.nl%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) is triggering quirks mode.

Comment: Thanks for your Doctype suggestion. Although there is a doctype specified, I see something strange in the header meta that is causing this thanks to your suggestion looking there, it is :<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> If I delete this it does work, but I can't oversee if this deletion of emulating gives any other errors. Is it an obsolete statement, if IE8- doesn't need to be supported?

Comment: @Inge - yes, the `EmulateIE7` is definitely going to be the problem. Replace `IE=EmulateIE7` with `IE=edge`. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: @Inge You don't need that statement, but you should fix the errors on the XHTML validator to ensure your site works as expected across browsers.

Comment: @Spudley The meta tag specifying `IE=edge` is not required when a valid standards-compliant doctype is specified, as it is in this instance.

Comment: @Starsong - please note that Compatibility mode is *not* the same as Quirks mode. Neither of them is a good thing, but they are very different; they are triggered differently and behave differently. It is important to know the difference. The issue here is with Compatibility mode, not Quirks mode. The (lack of a) doctype triggers quirks mode. The `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag triggers Compatibility mode. Some copies of IE are configured to use compatibility mode by default in some instances: Specifying `IE=edge` overrides this, so it *is* useful to specify it.

Comment: @Spudley You're right (compatibility mode acts like IE7, quirks mode acts like IE5), but the point still stands that the `IE=edge` statement is not required when specifying a valid doctype.

Comment: @Starsong: It's more complex than that. And trust me; yes `IE=edge` is useful for avoiding compatibility mode in cases when it might be used by default. And it really *isn't* intended for avoiding quirks mode; you do that by having a valid doctype.

Comment: @Starsong 'IE=edge' seems to solve this as far as I can see.  But you are saying that in fact the  (old)Doctype should be changed as well? I know the doctype is not HTML5 compatible, but since this site is coded some years ago, I don't want to change too much about this since it might give more strange behaviour.

Comment: @Inge You're fine to keep your doctype. I just suggest if you don't have one, use html5.

Comment: Ok, will keep it this way then, thanks both of you , totally working now. Usefull information.

Answer (score 3):

problem is because of something wrong in doctype, use `<!DOCTYPE html>` for html5 and to make it working on ie8 use

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

if you don't want html5 then use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

this will fix the problem i think

Comment: Why XHTML 1.1 instead of XHTML 1.0 Transitional?